# accept multiple models with a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I have a basic form setup of a supplier name and email. I would like to nest my attributes for address into this form, but I keep getting the below error

> Unpermitted parameter: address

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy, as: :addressable    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to  :supplier
end

class SuppliersController < ApplicationController

  def allowed_params
    params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, :email, {:address_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :address1, :address2, :city, :zip_code, :country_id]})
  end
end
```

Supplier Form

```
%fieldset#admin-supplier-names.span-12
  %label Name
  = form.text_field :name
  %label Email
  = form.text_field :email

= form.fields_for :address do |address_fields|
  %li= address_fields.text_field :first_name, placeholder: :first_name.upcase, value: current_user.first_name
  %li= address_fields.text_field :last_name, placeholder: :last_name, value: current_user.last_name
  %li= address_fields.text_field :address1, placeholder: :address_1
  %li= address_fields.text_field :address2, placeholder: :address_2
  %li= address_fields.text_field :city, placeholder: :city
  %li= address_fields.text_field :zip_code, placeholder: :post_code
  %li=address_fields.select   :country_id, select_countries, :include_blank => true
```

Comment: The association in supplier model is `has_many :addresses`?

Comment: @Pavan i have `has_many    :addresses,       dependent: :destroy,       as: :addressable`

Comment: If you have used 'belongs_to  :addressable, :polymorphic => true' then why are you using 'belongs_to  :supplier' , i mean why to use both of them, if one can serve your purpose ?

Comment: why don't you use cocoon? https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your association declaration between `supplier` and `address` and the form code are out of sync.

If your `supplier` can have only one `address`, then update your code where applicable with the following:

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class SuppliersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @supplier = Supplier.new
    @supplier.build_address
  end

  def edit
     @supplier = Supplier.find(params[:id])
     @supplier.build_address if @supplier.address.nil?
  end

  def allowed_params
    params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, :email, address_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :address1, :address2, :city, :zip_code, :country_id])
  end
end

%fieldset#admin-supplier-names.span-12
  %label Name
  = form.text_field :name
  %label Email
  = form.text_field :email

= form.fields_for :address do |address_fields|
  %li= address_fields.text_field :first_name, placeholder: :first_name.upcase, value: current_user.first_name
  %li= address_fields.text_field :last_name, placeholder: :last_name, value: current_user.last_name
  %li= address_fields.text_field :address1, placeholder: :address_1
  %li= address_fields.text_field :address2, placeholder: :address_2
  %li= address_fields.text_field :city, placeholder: :city
  %li= address_fields.text_field :zip_code, placeholder: :post_code
  %li=address_fields.select   :country_id, select_countries, :include_blank => true
```

But if your `supplier` can have many `addresses`, then update your code where applicable with the following:

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  have_many :addresses, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class SuppliersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @supplier = Supplier.new
    3.times { @supplier.addresses.build } #setup as many as you want
  end

  def edit
     @supplier = Supplier.find(params[:id])
     addresses_count = (3 - @supplier.addresses.count) 
     addresses_count.times { @supplier.addresses.build }
  end

  def allowed_params
    params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, :email, addresses_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :address1, :address2, :city, :zip_code, :country_id])
  end
end

%fieldset#admin-supplier-names.span-12
  %label Name
  = form.text_field :name
  %label Email
  = form.text_field :email

= form.fields_for :addresses do |address_fields|
  %li= address_fields.text_field :first_name, placeholder: :first_name.upcase, value: current_user.first_name
  %li= address_fields.text_field :last_name, placeholder: :last_name, value: current_user.last_name
  %li= address_fields.text_field :address1, placeholder: :address_1
  %li= address_fields.text_field :address2, placeholder: :address_2
  %li= address_fields.text_field :city, placeholder: :city
  %li= address_fields.text_field :zip_code, placeholder: :post_code
  %li=address_fields.select   :country_id, select_countries, :include_blank => true
```

Refer to [StrongParameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html), [FormBuilder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) for more info.

Comment: will this work for editing a supplier where the address has never been created?

Comment: It should, as the address/addresses are built both in new and edit actions.

Comment: interesting as it only appears to be working on new, when i go and choose edit on an existing supplier with no address the form fields arent being presented

Comment: which option did you end up using/testing? `supplier` has_one `address` or `supplier` has_many `addresses`?

Comment: You should include a link to gist with your updated code of models, controller and views, otherwise it is hard to tell where the issue is, as I double checked the proposal and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

> Unpermitted parameter: address

With your associations, you need to change `address` to `addresses` in `fields_for` and `allowed_params`.

```
= form.fields_for :addresses do |address_fields|
```

And in the controller's `allowed_params`

```
def allowed_params
  params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, :email, :addresses_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name, :address1, :address2, :city, :zip_code, :country_id])
end
```

Comment: now the address fields aren't appearing with that change

Comment: what I've also noted is when the params are getting transmitted via the forms they still come through as address not address_atttributes

Answer (score 0):

Please have look and update your code as shown below -:

```
  #-----controller----
  # GET /suppliers/new
 def new
  @supplier = Supplier.new
  @supplier.addresses.new
 end

 def allowed_params
   params.require(:supplier).permit(:name, :addresses_attributes=>  [:city]) # you can pass all your fields inside this array, i have tested for only one field i.e city.
 end

#-----update form field for nested attribute as shown below, append this inside your form(form_for(@suppier))
 <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |addr| %>
   <div>
     <%= addr.label :city %>
     <%= addr.text_field :city %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

Rest of your code is fine, just make the above changes and you are good to go... :)